# How can I position a georeferenced 3D object on AR inside Unreal 5?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, unreal

I want to know how can I position a 3D object georeferenced inside UE5 in augmented reality, using HandleAR content. Basically, I want to position a 3D object on the front door of my house, so when I open my app made with the HandledAR preset and point the camera of my smartphone to the front door of my house, I can see it. I've been searching and the part of georeferencing my 3d object confuses me, so I need most help with position this inside my level in Unreal in a way that it stands in the front door my house. Please someone help me! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site works best with specific programming questions. See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/295004)